# Create a file if it does not exist and write 0 in this file, otherwise do nothing

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash, I want to check if a file exists, if exist, do nothing. If not, create a new file and write "0" in this new file.

I wrote the following code, The problem is: this code will overwrite the existing file. Could anyone tell me where is wrong? How should I revise it?

```
for r in FE C CR MN SI NI CO MO W NB AL P CU TA V B N O S
do
  if [ ! -f id1/data/T1_FCC_X_${r}.dat ]; then
    echo "0"  > data/T1_FCC_X_${r}.dat
  fi
done
```

Comment: you check for file `id1/. ..` yet you write to file `data/...`

Comment: Thank you. My idea is: firstly check if this file exists, if not, create a new file and write 0 into it. But it should not overwrite existing file. How should I revise this code?

Comment: @JPeng previous comment already points you in the correct direction. You are currently checking for existence of file (`[ -f ...]`) in a different directory (for so for a different file) than the one you are writing into with `echo "0" > ...`. Make sure that file you check for and write into are both the same.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in just one shot with the [`noclobber`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) option:

> Prevent output redirection using `>`, `>&`, and `<>` from overwriting existing files.

From the [Redirecting Output section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output):

> If the redirection operator is `>`, and the `noclobber` option to the `set` builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file.

So this should do:

```
set -o noclobber  # or, equivalently, set -C

for r in FE C CR MN SI NI CO MO W NB AL P CU TA V B N O S; do
    echo "0" > "data/T1_FCC_X_$r.dat"
done 2> /dev/null
```

If the file exists, the redirection fails with an error message on standard error (and the file isn't overwritten at all); that's why we redirect the error message to `/dev/null` (after the loop), so as to not pollute the standard error stream.

If the file doesn't exist, then the redirection will be performed, provided that you have all the rights to create such a file.

**Note.** You might want to unset `noclobber` after this: `set +o noclobber` (or include everything in a subshell).